# Openni_launch does not recognize ''device_id" argument for PrimeSense

Tags: ros, primesense, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a kinect and a PrimeSense v2 device. If I only plug in the kinect and set the device_id argument to "#1" for first device, it runs the kinect and displays the device_id. I can then use the 'device_id' argument to make sure that kinect is always referred to by a particular camera name. So far so good.
If I plug in only the PrimeSense and select first device, it will find it, display the device_id, and run properly. However, when I enter in that device_id as an argument, I get this warning at run time: **"~device_id is not set! Using first device".** The only difference I can see is that the kinect id is 16 digits hexadecimal, while the PrimeSense is 10 digits decimal.
I tried padding the PrimeSense id with spaces or 0's in front, but it still tells me the device_id is not set.
I also a variety of other, made up id's. As far as I can see, the id must include a letter for it to be recognized. If I add characters in front of the actual id, it recognizes the string as a device_id but doesn't recognize it as matching the real device. Some goes for placing' on either side of the number- it is comparing '(number)' to ''(number)''- or converting the id to hexadecimal.
What is the proper way to specify this device? I am working in a multi-device environment and need to assign the proper names to the proper devices. I know that there is an option to specify usb hubs or something, but I would rather not rely on port id's.

Thank you for your help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71530/openni_launch-does-not-recognize-%27%27device_id%22-argument-for-primesense/) by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
maybe a bit too late, but may be helpful for other readers:

You need to add the attribute type="string" to the device_id parameter in device.launch

/opt/ros/groovy/share/openni_launch/launch/includes/device.launch

Change Line 30 (groovy) from:

`<param name="device_id" value="$(arg device_id)" />`

to

`<param name="device_id" value="$(arg device_id)" type="string" />`

---

Originally posted by [tsparber](https://answers.ros.org/users/9821/tsparber/) with karma: 36 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tsparber](https://answers.ros.org/users/9821/tsparber/) on 2014-03-25**:
related: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/pull/13